# JavaScript Login Form Redirect

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

I am trying to make simple javascript login (I know it's not secure), but the Login button isn't redirecting me where I want. I want it to redirect me to 'home.html' but instead it is redirecting me to the login page 'index.html'. Where is problem?
Here is my JavaScript code:

```
function Login(form) {
username = new Array("admin");
password = new Array("test");
if (form.username.value == username[0] && form.password.value == password[0]) {
location.href='home.html';
return false;
}
else {
alert("Either the username or password you entered is incorrect.\nPlease try again.");
form.username.focus();
}
return true;
}
```

And here is my html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript" src="login.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form class="box" method="post">
<input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username">
<input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
<input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="Login(this.form)" value="Login">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it gets there then check the path of the file

Comment: Use `event.preventDefault()` or `return false` to stop form submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added `return false;` after calling my `Login` function in the input field's `onclick` handler, and it's working!

```html
<input type="submit" id="mySubmit" onclick="Login(this.form); return false;" value="Login">
```